# Template tag as filter value in Django

Tags: django

I have defined one custom tag which is working fine in templates.
Like

```
{% get_setting "DATE_FORMAT_UI" %}
```

Above statement is returning correct value in template.
Now i want to use the same in a filter like this -

```
{{extra_info.to_date|date: '{% get_setting "DATE_FORMAT_UI" %}' }}
```

But this is giving error in parsing.
I tried in different ways of using quotes for the `{% get_setting "DATE_FORMAT_UI" %}`

But every time bad luck.

So could any body help me in solving this. I want to pass date format in filter . That date format is saved into config file. but how to pass that value dynamically in filter.

Answer (score 2):

The trick is to first assign this to a variable (here `myformat`), and then use that variable:

```
{% get_setting 'DATE_FORMAT_UI' as myformat %}
{{extra_info.to_date|date:myformat }}
```

Comment: It worked !  I got the concept.   A big big thanks  @Willem Van Onsem